# Using .NET Standard in Xamarin iOS

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-standard, typeloadexception

I have added a reference to a **.NET Standard Library** (1.3) in my **Xamarin iOS** project.

In runtime, when I create an instance of a **class defined in the .NET Standard Library**, it throws this exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method due to a type load
>   error

For example, it happens when I do:

```
var c = new Customer();
```

What's happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to remove the app from your device, delete bin and obj and rebuild. Sometimes, things are missing for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it: The problem was that I had to include transitive references. That is, my project A references B, and B references C. So I had to include A => C. Not pretty obvious. I also had to include all the NuGet packages my references use. Building and running now!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This problem still exists and makes the use of libraries quite senseless.